# dropdown values load sometimes and sometimes not in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs , where I am loading dropdowns from database in angularjs controller. I am facing an intermittent issue that sometimes dropdown values load and sometimes don't . Its working on my local but when I upload on server this intermittent issue is coming.

I have even tried to use `ng-init` on html and then put login there in that function but still this issue is there.

here is html

```
<div class="x_panel" ng-init="loadDropDownData()">
    <div class="x_title">

        <h2 id="EditjobTitle" style="display:none">Edit Job<small></small></h2>
        <button class="btn col-md-offset-9" id="btnBack" style="display:none" ng-click="Cancel()">Back</button>

        <h2 id="NewjobTitle">New Engagement<small></small></h2>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

<div class="x_content">
        <br>
        <form name="JobForm" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 save-buttons">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="JobForm.$valid && save()">Save</button>
                    <button class="btn" ng-click="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5>Job Data</h5>
            <input type="hidden" id="JobID" ng_value="{{Job.JobNum}}">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Job Name", new { @class = "control-label control-label-j col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="JobName" ng-model="Job.JobName" ng-minlength="4" id="txtJobName" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="" maxlength=25>
                </div>

                @Html.Label("EngType", new { @class = "control-label control-label-j col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="EngType" ng-model="Job.EngType" ng-options="s.ID as s.EngTypes for s in Job.lstEngType" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="">
                        <option value="">-- Select EngType --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

and Js file is as below

```
app.controller('AddJobController', function ($scope, $location, $filter, ShareData, jobService, $compile) {
    $scope.phoneNumbr = /^\+?\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/;
    $scope.datePattern = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/i
    $scope.regEx = "/^[0-9]{10,10}$/;";
    $scope.listOfStatus = [];
    $scope.showStatusError = false;
    $scope.statusText = "";

    $scope.loadDropDownData = function() {

        loadJobInitdata();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txtCloseDate").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $("#txtDraft_Date").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $("#txtFinal_Date").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $("#txtOpenDate").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $("#txtFinalSent").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $('body').off('click', '.remove-record').on('click', '.remove-record', function () {
            removeSpan = "";
            var addButton = "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>\
                            <input type='button'  class='btn btnAddDeadline' value='Add Deadline' />\
                        </div>";
            var ifAdd = false;
            if ($(this).parent().find('.btnAddDeadline').length == 1) {
                ifAdd = true;
            }
            if ($scope.Job.JobNum != null && $scope.Job.JobNum != undefined) {
                var ID = $(this).parent().find('.deadline-datepicker').attr('id')
                ID = ID.replace("Date", "");
                var removeSpanElement = $(this);
                if (ID != "txtDeadlines") {
                    var promiseDeleteDeadline = jobService.DeleteDeadline(ID)
                    promiseDeleteDeadline.then(function () {
                        removeSpanElement.parent().remove();
                        if (ifAdd) {
                            PopulateDeadline(null, addButton, removeSpan);
                            $('.deadline-datepicker').datepicker({
                                ignoreReadonly: true,
                                startDate: new Date()
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    if (ifAdd) {
                        PopulateDeadline(null, addButton, removeSpan);
                        $('.deadline-datepicker').datepicker({
                            ignoreReadonly: true,
                            startDate: new Date()
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                if (ifAdd) {
                    PopulateDeadline(null, addButton, removeSpan);
                    $('.deadline-datepicker').datepicker({
                        ignoreReadonly: true,
                        startDate: new Date()
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    })



    if (ShareData.value == 0) {
        //loadJobInitdata();
    }
    else {
        Edit();
    }
    $scope.maxlength = 3;
    $scope.Job = [];
    function Edit() {
        if (!ShareData.createAsNewJob) {
            $('#NewjobTitle').hide();
            $('#EditjobTitle').show();
            $('#btnBack').show();
        }
        //loadJobInitdata();
        var promiseEditjobData = jobService.EditJob(ShareData.value);
        promiseEditjobData.then(function (jobdata) {
            GetDeadlinesbyJobID(ShareData.value);
            getStatusCommentsJobId(ShareData.value);
                $scope.Job = jobdata.data;
            var CloseDate = $scope.Job.CloseDate = (jobdata.data.CloseDate != null && jobdata.data.CloseDate != undefined) ? $filter('date')(new Date(jobdata.data.CloseDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : null
            var OpenDate = $scope.Job.OpenDate = jobdata.data.OpenDate = (jobdata.data.OpenDate != null && jobdata.data.OpenDate != undefined) ? $filter('date')(new Date(jobdata.data.OpenDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : null
            var Draft_Date = $scope.Job.Draft_Date = jobdata.data.Draft_Date = (jobdata.data.Draft_Date != null && jobdata.data.Draft_Date != undefined) ? $filter('date')(new Date(jobdata.data.Draft_Date), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : null
            var Final_Date = $scope.Job.Final_Date = jobdata.data.Final_Date = (jobdata.data.Final_Date != null && jobdata.data.Final_Date != undefined) ? $filter('date')(new Date(jobdata.data.Final_Date), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : null
            $scope.Job.Deadlines = jobdata.data.Deadlines = (jobdata.data.Deadlines != null && jobdata.data.Deadlines != undefined) ? $filter('date')(new Date(jobdata.data.Deadlines), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : null
            console.log(new Date(CloseDate));
            var myDate = new Date(1978, 2, 11)
            if (CloseDate != null) { $("#txtCloseDate").datepicker("update", new Date(CloseDate)); }
            if (OpenDate != null) { $("#txtOpenDate").datepicker("update", new Date(OpenDate)); }
            if (Draft_Date != null) { $("#txtDraft_Date").datepicker("update", new Date(Draft_Date)); }
            if (Final_Date != null) { $("#txtFinal_Date").datepicker("update", new Date(Final_Date)); }
            ShareData.value = 0;
            if (ShareData.createAsNewJob == true) {
                $scope.Job.JobNum = null;
                ShareData.createAsNewJob = false;
            }
        },
        function (errorPl) {
            $scope.error = errorPl;
            ShareData.value = 0;
            alert($scope.error);
        });
    }









    function loadJobInitdata() {

        var promiseLoadDLLs = jobService.GetJobInitData();
        promiseLoadDLLs.then(function (pl) {
            //$scope.Job = pl.data
            $scope.Job.lstEngType = pl.data.lstEngType,
            $scope.Job.lstWorkProduct = pl.data.lstWorkProduct,
            $scope.Job.lstNAICSCode = pl.data.lstNAICSCode,
            $scope.Job.lstSubject = pl.data.lstSubject,
            $scope.Job.lstManager = pl.data.lstManager,
            $scope.Job.lstClientType = pl.data.lstClientType,
            $scope.Job.lstFeeBasis = pl.data.lstFeeBasis,
            $scope.Job.lstBillingCycle = pl.data.lstBillingCycle,
            $scope.Job.lstExpenses = pl.data.lstExpenses,
            $scope.Job.lstSalesperson = pl.data.lstSalesperson,
            $scope.Job.lstPriority = pl.data.lstPriority,
            $scope.Job.lstStaff = pl.data.lstStaff,
            $scope.Job.lstLogo_in_Client_Logo_File = pl.data.lstLogo_in_Client_Logo_File,
            $scope.Job.lstTombstone_Status = pl.data.lstTombstone_Status
        },
              function (errorPl) {
                  $scope.error = errorPl;
                  alert($scope.error);
              });
    }



    $scope.Cancel = function () {
        $location.path(ShareData.page);
    }

    $scope.AddDeadline = AddDeadline;



});
```

Comment: For dropdown you're referring to the `select` shown in your HTML. Is that right?

Comment: yes, select I am referring to

Comment: And, when the data is not shown on the html...are you sure it's coming from database successfully? In the web browser dev tools are you able to see the data in the server response despite in the html it isn't shown?

Comment: yes, because its same record, sometimes dropdowns load and sometimes it doesn't and on local it always